# Django Sentry Import error

Tags: django, sentry, raven

I have just installed django-sentry and plan to use it for logging in my django project. But I have run into a roadblock.

This is the error that I get, whenever I try to log an error:

```
    Unable to record event: cannot import name Group
```

Relevant stack I am using:

```
    django-paging   - 0.2.4
    django-indexer  - 0.3.0
    django-templatetag-sugar - 0.1
    django-sentry   - 1.13.5 
    raven           - 3.1.15 
    eventlet        - 0.12.1
    greenlet        - 0.4.0 
    lockfile        - 0.9.1   
    python-daemon   - 1.6
```

This is what I do:

```
    import logging
    logger=logging.getLogger('sentry.error')
    logger.error('error message')
```

Logging settings defined in settings.py:

```
    SENTRY_LOGGING = {
        'version': 1,
        'disable_existing_loggers': True,
        'root': {
            'level': 'WARNING',
            'handlers': ['sentry']
        },
        'formatters': {
            'verbose': {
                'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
            }
        },
        'handlers': {
            'sentry': {
                'level': 'DEBUG',
                'class': 'raven.contrib.django.handlers.SentryHandler'
            },
            'console': {
                'level': 'DEBUG',
                'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
                'formatter': 'verbose'
            },
            'mail_admins': {
                'level': 'ERROR',
                'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
            }
        },
        'loggers': {
            'django.db.backends': {
                'level': 'ERROR',
                'handlers': ['console'],
                'propagate': False
            },
            'raven': {
                'level': 'DEBUG',
                'handlers': ['console'],
                'propagate': False
            },
            'sentry.errors': {
                'level': 'DEBUG',
                'handlers': ['console'],
                'propagate': False
            },
            'django.request': {
                'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
                'level': 'ERROR',
                'propagate': True
            }
        }
    }
```

Stack trace of the exception:

```
    ERROR 2013-02-25 16:07:56,938 client 17887 140238506051328 Unable to record event: cannot import name Group
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/user/src/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/raven/contrib/django/client.py", line 148, in send
        return self.send_integrated(kwargs)
      File "/home/user/src/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/raven/contrib/django/client.py", line 153, in send_integrated
        from sentry.models import Group
    ImportError: cannot import name Group
```

I am trying to figure out what is going wrong, but without luck till now. My hunch is it might be a version problem between Raven and Sentry.

Please help me out if you have any idea what might be causing the problem.

In case I missed some info, do let me know.

Thanks!!

Comment: Are you have groups in http://sentry.url/admin/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was because of version conflicts of sentry and raven. Please check the versions at the time of installing. I used raven 3.3.3.